# Java regular expression to remove all non alphanumeric characters EXCEPT spaces

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression in Java which removes all non-alphanumeric characters from a paragraph, except the spaces between the words.

This is the code I've written:

```
paragraphInformation = paragraphInformation.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]", "");
```

However, the compiler gave me an error message pointing to the s saying it's an illegal escape character.  The program compiled OK before I added the \s to the end of the regular expression, but the problem with that was that the spaces between words in the paragraph were stripped out.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You need to double-escape the `\` character: `"[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]"`

Java will interpret `\s` as a Java String escape character, which is indeed an invalid Java escape. By writing `\\`, you escape the `\` character, essentially sending a single `\` character to the regex. This `\` then becomes part of the regex escape character `\s`.

Answer (score 15):

You need to escape the \ so that the regular expression recognizes \s :

```
paragraphInformation = paragraphInformation.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]", "");
```

Answer (score 5):

Generally whenever you see that error, it means you only have a single backslash where you need two:

```
paragraphInformation = paragraphInformation.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]", "");
```

Answer (score 4):

Victoria, you must write `\\s` not `\s` here.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this site, you can test Java Regex online and get wellformatted regex string patterns back:

http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html