# how i remove characters points characters especial in java

Tags: java, regex

how i do a regex for remove characters especial in java but i want that keep spaces and accentuation (é ã etc ) in words, i just want remove characters like (+/-*.",', etc) and number

i try this but this remove all letter with accentuation
texto.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ] ","")

my intention is get a texte random in internet and split this text in a array String how my lenguage have letter with acentuation i want keep they, and use space " " how delimiter for splite the text

input:

```
Servindo, ao exército prussiano - contra a (França durante a Guerra da Primeira) Coligação, ele constatou que as rações
```

output:
Servindo
ao
exército
prussiano
contra
a

kepping acents in words and 1 pace beetwen the words
..etc

Comment: See this if it may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796985/java-regular-expression-to-remove-all-non-alphanumeric-characters-except-spaces?rq=1

Comment: Add some example input/output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to remove punctuation characters and numbers from string.

You can just use special regex properties for that:

```
String repl = inputs.replaceAll("[\\p{Punct}\\p{N}]+", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

This code would search for special Characters like %$§ and replace it with that character you want. Enjoy

```
private void remove(String text) {
        System.out.println(String.format("before: '%s'", text));
        if (text != null && text.trim().length() != 0) {
            text = text.replaceAll("\\W+", "");
            System.out.println(String.format("after: '%s'", text));
        }
    }
```