# Get all not matching characters from a regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex `/[A-Za-z./-]+`, and the text that I want to test is `ABCD123`. After the text doesn't pass the regex, I want to display the characters that are not contained at all in the regex. So in this case, I want to display 123 or (1,2,3). How can I do this ?

The question is for java.

LE: The code accepts general regexes and general texts so it has to be a general solution.

Comment: What language are you using? Rather just match everything that isn't a letter. Then you have your 123 (or 1,2,3)

Comment: The code accepts general regexes and general texts so it has to be a general solution.

Comment: There are various flavours of regex, `([^a-zA-Z]{1,})` will work on bigquery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract a substring using regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662215/how-to-extract-a-substring-using-regex)

Answer (score 2):

You can also first check that regexp pass, when not - remove characters by another regexp, and then you will be have only that not passed characters.

Pseudo code:

```
if string is not '[A-Za-z./-]+' then
    wrong_chars = string.remove('[A-Za-z./-]+')
```

Comment: Can you remove from a String characters specified by a regex ? Because if this is the case, then this is the solution.

Comment: First result from Google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796985/java-regular-expression-to-remove-all-non-alphanumeric-characters-except-spaces

Comment: The regex can start for example with a "/", and then allow for letter. How do I eliminate only the letters ? The regex doesn't have any method "regex.contains("A")", so how can I elminiate A from ABC if the regex is "/[A]" ?

Answer (score 2):

```
([^a-zA-Z]{1,})
```

Will match your pattern.

As will, more succinctly:

```
 [^a-zA-Z]+
```

Comment: Why does this work and `([^a-zA-Z]*)` does not?

Comment: * matches beween 0 and unlimited times while + matches between 1 and unlimited. Obvously, we don't want the match of 0 in this case.

Comment: It took me a while to see but negatively matching 0 times indeed doesn't make sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to just negate your regex :`/([A-Za-z.\/-]+)|([^A-Za-z.\/-]+)/g`

Second capturing group is the group which will have elements not matched.

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/fI3aO0/4)

Comment: FYI right side of alternation can become shorter to `(.)`

Comment: You didn't include the first /. Why not ? Beside, the expression can be general and I receive it as a parameter.

Comment: If your regex has a must on using slash at the very beginning then your input string `ABCD123` is never matched and expected result should be A,B,C,D,1,2,3 and not only 1,2,3. You should clarify this problem. @VisanCosmin

Answer (score 0):

Include an alternation which captures all other characters:

```
[A-Za-z.\/-]+|(.)
```

This way if left side of alternation does not match whole input string then first capturing group has some values in it.

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/jK5eN8/1)